# This error is a teapot?

Tags: bug, images

So I was trying to upload a photo, and I received an error:

`Request returned an error: [error] I'm a teapot`

Have we switched image uploads to [HTCPCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol)?!

For some reason I got logged out of my account, even on Stack Overflow. I logged back in, refreshed the page, and everything was reverted to a prior revision of what I was writing. Fortunately, I didn't loose too much work, otherwise I'd be *boiling*.

[Related Über-meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426)

Here's a picture of what happened:

[image: Are you really?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We return that error in a few scenarios where we have decided (for various reasons) that we really don't trust the incoming request - usually protection from botnets, hack attempts, attempts from external sites to hijack your account (XSRF failure), etc. I'm not saying that you did any of these things; I suspect something changed on your connection sufficiently to cause a false-positive. Sorry about that. If it is working *now*, then we're probably fine. Unfortunately, a small number of false-positives is a side-effect of the hostile internet in which we reside :(